# Function for two users

Tags: python, function

I have a log in system for two users. I had duplicate code for it but I made it a function to make the code more efficient. However, I am not too sure how to make some variables change for each user. Here is the code:

```
def login_system():
    loggedin = False
    while not loggedin:
        login=input("Do you have an account? (yes/no) ")
        loggedin=False
        if login.lower()=="yes":
            login=open("login.csv")
            reader = csv.reader(login)
            username=input("What is your username: ")
            password=input("What is your password: ")
            for row in reader:
                if row[0]==username and row[1]==password:
                    print("Welcome " + username)
                    loggedin=True
                    break
            if loggedin==False:
                print("Invalid username or password. Please try again.")
                continue

        elif login.lower()=="no":
            print(" ")
            print("Make an account.")
            print(" ")
            username=input("What is your username: ")
            password=input("What is your password: ")
            break

        else:
            print("Invalid input.")
            continue
print("User 1:")
login_system()

print("")
print("User 2:")
login_system()
```

Basically, I want to have username and password different for user 1 to user 2 but I have no idea where to start and nothing seems to help. When I input the username and password for user two, it overwrites the input I made for user one and I don't want that happening. Thanks,

Dylan

Comment: It depends on the content of your `login.csv` - I notice, for example, that when a user "makes an account" you aren't saving their details to the file, or indeed doing anything with them. (And I'm assuming this is just a toy example for fun and practice - a real user login system would use a database, not just a file, and wouldn't store passwords in plaintext. If by any chance this is something you're planning to use in "real life", please research how to do it properly.)

Comment: The part where it puts the details into the CSV is later into the code because its a login for a game so i put it after the game to make it easier. It appends the username, password and then score. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's the problem actually ?

Comment: The variable username and password is written into a csv file at the end of the code but i had duplicate code to begin with. I wanted to make it shorter so i made it a function. However, i write the first username and password in and then the second username and password overwrite the first ones. I want it so it doesn't overwrite them.

Answer (score 0):

It  seems you are practicing python or a simple question, well I have added the Pseudo code which you can develop yourself because it is simple and if you write this yourself it will help you think in that paradigm inorder to solve this problem.

Whenever you want to do something or implement it, do it in steps or write it down, it helps alot.

Read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) btw.

```
 def login_system():
        loggedin = False
        while not loggedin:
            login=input("Do you have an account? (yes/no) ")
            loggedin=False
            if login.lower()=="yes":
                login=open("login.csv")
                reader = csv.reader(login)
                username=input("What is your username: ")
                password=input("What is your password: ")
                for row in reader:
                    if row[0]==username and row[1]==password:
                        print("Welcome " + username)
                        loggedin=True
                        break
                if loggedin==False:
                    print("Invalid username or password. Please try again.")
                    continue

            elif login.lower()=="no":
                print(" ")
                print("Make an account.")
                print(" ")
                username=input("What is your username: ")
                password=input("What is your password: ")
                #How to Save Username and password
                #1. Find Two Empty Rows or one empty row and it's corresponding column in CSV file. (Can be done using running a loop on the csv file)
                #2. Store Username password in the corresponding rows and columns above. 


                break

            else:
                print("Invalid input.")
                continue
    print("User 1:")
    login_system()

    print("")
    print("User 2:")
    login_system()
```

Comment: Then you can read the rows and columns of the CSV files and match them accordingly when you want to login any user.

Answer (score -1):

As per your requirements it seems that dictionary of successfully logged in usernames and passwords could be better for you if you store them

Make your code as belows.

```
users_logged_in={}
def login_system():
loggedin = False
while not loggedin:
    login=input("Do you have an account? (yes/no) ")
    loggedin=False
    if login.lower()=="yes":
        login=open("login.csv")
        reader = csv.reader(login)
        username=input("What is your username: ")
        password=input("What is your password: ")
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]==username and row[1]==password:
                print("Welcome " + username)
                #  usernames and passwords you have entered stored in dict
                users_logged_in[username]=password
                loggedin=True
                break
        if loggedin==False:
            print("Invalid username or password. Please try again.")
            continue

    elif login.lower()=="no":
        print(" ")
        print("Make an account.")
        print(" ")
        username=input("What is your username: ")
        password=input("What is your password: ")
        break

    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
        continue
print("User 1:")
login_system()

print("")
print("User 2:")
login_system()
```

If you want the order of the usernames logged in to system to be preserved go to **OrderedDict** from Python collections.

Else you could create list with tuples of usernames and passwords
Create tuple as below in above code

```
logged_user_details=(username,passowrd)
```

and let

> users_logged_in

be a list of usernames and passwords, Append to it the tuple created above.

```
users_logged_in.append(logged_user_details).
```

Now you would have users and passwords in your list as shown below and order of your entry will also be preserved.

> [(User1,Password1),(User2,Password2),(User3,Password3)].

It is entirely dependent on your usage purpose of storing username and password whether you go with List or Dict approach.

Comment: Using two distinct lists and relying on the lists ordering to match usernames and passwords is brittle and ineffficient - you want a username:password dict instead, or at least a single list of username,password tuples.

Comment: I am about to do the same